# passing information from Postsharp aspect to actual method

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I'm not sure if this can be done, as logically it doesn't make sense to me.  I've been testing out Postsharp aspects and AOP in general, and I can greatly see the benefits they can bring to a codebase.

I use RavenDB (document database) and sometimes I have 'tasks' which basically they would have to create a session object, do some logic, and then call session.SaveChanges() after.  This would be extremely beneficial for a `TaskAspect` which would basically do the session creation and calls `.SaveChanges()` after.

The main issue is that sometimes, when new documents are created in the business logic, one needs to call `session.Store(newObject)`.  The issue is that the session is not available in the actual method, as it would have been created in the `MethodInterceptionAspect`.

Below is a very basic `TaskAspect` implementation and sample logic:

```
[Serializable]
public class TaskAspect : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        var session = RavenUtil.CreateSession();

        args.Proceed();

        session.SaveChanges();
        session.Dispose();
        base.OnInvoke(args);
    }

}

public class SampleLogic
{
      [TaskAspect]
      public void CreateItem()
      {
            var product = new Product();
            session.Store(product);   //<---- how can I obtain this session, as it is created in the aspect??

      }


}
```

The issue as you can see is that the call to `args.Proceed()` doesn't know about the session.  Any ideas how one can pass such information?  Does it make sense first of all, or is this logic flawed and I shouldn't be using aspects for this?

One thought that came to mind was to store the session in a `ThreadStatic` variable, but I think it is very 'ugly'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you could use a `[ThreadStatic]` field (the type would probably need to be `Stack<Session>`).

You could also define a parameter in your method (perhaps set a default null value) and have the aspect set the parameter before calling `Proceed`. To set the parameter, use `args.Arguments`.

Comment: I've been playing around with aspects and I've coincidentally tried exactly those two options and they work good.  Prefer the 2nd option, expecting a parameter which is always NULL and the aspect fills it in.  I then added checks to make sure that the parameter is of the expected type, and that it is always passed as NULL as defensive programming. Thanks!